# TypeError: Discord.Streaming is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
await client.change_presence(
 (activity = Discord.Streaming((name = 'text'), (url = 'twitch url')))
);
```

How can I get my bot to have a purple status and stream on twitch without having any errors?

I just realized that I followed a `.py` tutorial instead of `.js`... So I'm trying to turn it into `json` please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.user.setActivity('text here', { type: 'STREAMING', url: 'twitch url' });
```

This will work!